# adding items to a list in a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm trying to put values into a dictionary dependent on the key...  For example, if in a list of keys at the index 0 there is a letter "a". I want to add the val with index 0 to a list inside of a dictionary with the key "a" ( dictionary (key is "a" at index 0 , val at index 0) ... dictionary (key is "b" at index 2 , val at index 2))

I'm expecting an output like this:

> in listview lv1: 1,2,4 in listview lv2: 3,5
>
> what I'm getting is 3,4,5 in both listviews

```
List<string> key = new List<string>();
List<long> val = new List<long>();
List<long> tempList = new List<long>();
Dictionary<string, List<long>> testList = new Dictionary<string, List<long>>();

key.Add("a");
key.Add("a");
key.Add("b");
key.Add("a");
key.Add("b");
val.Add(1);
val.Add(2);
val.Add(3);
val.Add(4);
val.Add(5);    

for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{

    if (testList.ContainsKey(key[index]))
    {
        testList[key[index]].Add(val[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        tempList.Clear();
        tempList.Add(val[index]);
        testList.Add(key[index], tempList);
    }
}    
lv1.ItemsSource = testList["a"];
lv2.ItemsSource = testList["b"];
```

Solution:

replace the else code section with :

testList.Add(key[index], new List { val[index] });

thx everybody for your help =)

Comment: im adding a key only if it does not already exist... if (testList.ContainsKey(key[index]))....

Comment: You clear `tempList` when you get to key[3], because "b" isn't in testList yet.  So you end up with `tempList` containing {3,4,5}; the value for both elements in the dictionary is a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are using the same list for both keys in the Dictionary

```
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        if (testList.ContainsKey(key[index]))
        {
            testList[k].Add(val[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            testList.Add(key[index], new List<long>{val[index]});
        }
    }
```

Just create one new List(Of Long) when the key doesn't exists then add the long value to it

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of the `tempList` and replace your `else` clause with:

```
testList.Add(key[index], new List<long> { val[index] });
```

And don't use `Contains`. `TryGetValue` is much better:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
    int k = key[index];
    int v = val[index];
    List<long> items;
    if (testList.TryGetValue(k, out items))
    {
        items.Add(v);
    }
    else
    {
        testList.Add(k, new List<long> { v });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace else with:

```
else
{
    tempList.Clear();
    tempList.Add(val[index]);
    testList.Add(key[index], new List<long>(tempList));
}
```

The problem is, you are adding a reference to TempList to both keys, it is the same reference so it gets replaced in the first one.

I am creating a new list so it doesn't get replaced: `new List<long>(tempList)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework problem, but

```
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
    if (!testList.ContainsKey(key[index]))
        testList.Add(key[index], new List<string> {value[index]});
    else
        testList[key[index]].Add(value[index]);
}
```

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (and the other relevant tutorials)

Comment: Are you sure that's going to work? If an item with `key[index]` doesn't exist in the dictionary, `testList[key[index]]` is going to be `null`, resulting in a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do here, but I guarantee you didn't want the same list in every dictionary entry.

templist is your problem swap `templist.Clear()` for `templist = new List<Long>()`

Or go for

```
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
if (!testList.ContainsKey(key[Index]))
{
testList.Add(key[Index], new List<Long>());
}
testList[key[index]].Add(val[index]);
}
```